# Reading filenames from the directory

Tags: python

I want to get **two separate lists** of file names using glob, with each list having the same type of files. I have two type of data files. For example,

1. 2018-01-02.dat
2. 2018-01-02_patients.dat

The only difference is that the second file type is followed by "_patients". A date can be anything but the format is consistent. How can I accomplish this using glob?

Comment: `glob.glob('*_patients.dat')` ?

Comment: But I need to get the first type of files as well

Comment: `glob.glob('[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9].dat')`

Comment: Do you _need_ to use glob? There are much better tools for matching patterns. In this case I would use regular expressions and `os.listdir`.

Comment: No I don't need to use glob!

Answer (score 3):

To precisely match the digits, you can use the *glob* patterns:

```
[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9].dat  # matches e.g. 2018-01-02.dat
[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]_patients.dat  # matches e.g. 2018-01-02_patients.dat
```

You can also use the `?` instead of `[0-9]` to match any single character, if you are sure about the absence of any other alike patterns.

```
In [103]: glob.glob('[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9].dat')
Out[103]: ['2018-01-02.dat', '2014-03-12.dat']

In [104]: glob.glob('[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]_patients.dat')
Out[104]: ['2018-01-02_patients.dat', '2014-03-12_patients.dat']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re` with `glob`:

```
import glob
import re
final_files = [i for i in glob.glob('*') if re.findall('\.dat$|_patients\.dat$', i)]
```

Comment: OP said *How can I accomplish this using glob?*

Comment: @heemayl this answer does use `glob` and only introduces `re` to shorten the code.

Answer (score 0):

If those are the only two types of files in the directory, just use two lists and remove the duplicates from the bigger one, that way you will have the required lists.
Something like this..

```
list1 = glob.glob('*.dat')
list2 = glob.glob('*_patients.dat')

result_list_2 = list2
result_list_1 = [x for x in list1 if x not in list2]
```

Answer (score 0):

`touch 2018-01-02_patients.dat 2018-01-02.dat 1980-01-02.dat 1980-01-02_patients.dat`

pgm:

```
import glob
li = glob.glob("????-*-*.dat")

patients = [fn for fn in li if "patients." in fn]
dates = [fn for fn in li if not "_patients." in fn]

print ("patients", patients)
print ("dates", dates)
```

output:

```
('patients', ['1980-01-02_patients.dat', '2018-01-02_patients.dat'])
('dates', ['1980-01-02.dat', '2018-01-02.dat'])
```

Answer (score 0):

`glob` isn't particularly well suited to this task, but regular expressions are. You can use `os.listdir(path` to get a list of all files and use `re.match` to ensure the presence of a date, maybe followed by "_patients", definitely followed by ".dat". Here's how I'd do that:

```
import re
import os

pattern = '[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}(_patients)?\.dat$'
def is_patient_file(filename):
    return re.match(pattern, filename) is not None

def get_patient_files(path):
    all_files = os.listdir(path)
    return filter(is_patient_file, all_files)

print(get_patient_files('.'))
```

The parts of the regular expression are:

- the date: `[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}`

  - that is, four digits, dash, two digits, dash, two digits.
- maybe patients: `(_patients)?`
- definitely .dat: `\.dat`
- and no more: `$`